# Making an external object available in middleware code

Tags: reactjs, middleware, redux

So I have this problem. I have packed my React+Redux app into one file using Webpack. I made it so that the React
renders by using an init function.

```
var api = {
    init: function(rootDiv, anAPIObject) {
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <div>
                    <MyApp />
                </div>
            </Provider>,
            document.getElementById(rootDiv)
        );
    }
};

module.exports = api;


Foobar.init(rootDiv, anAPIObject);
```

However, I also want to pass a second argument(as seen above) that I plan to use in middleware code. It is some sort of an API library that needs to be external to the React+Redux code.

```
const aMiddleware = store => next => action => {
    // TODO: Use anAPIObject here
}

export default aMiddleware;
```

Is there a way to make `anAPIObject` be available in the middleware?

Comment: you mean to say you want to use anAPIObject in MyApp?

Comment: @DhavalPatel Technically, yes. But I would only plan to use it in middleware code.

Comment: Why don't you make one seperate store which can behave like middleware you can use it in each component

Answer (score 0):

You can create one middleware.js file and use it in component like

```
module.exports = {
  Func1: function() {
    return "HELLO";
  },

  Funmc2: function() {
    return "Hola";
  }
};
```

and in MyApp Component you can use

```
var Middleware=require('./Middleware');
Middleware.Func1()
```